# changing spotlight default to search file names, not contents

Tags: macos, osx-lion, spotlight

Does anyone know if it's possible to change the Spotlight default search behavior to search file names, not contents? Right now, bringing up the Spotlight field and typing "terrible" brings up a bunch of documents that have the word "terrible" somewhere in them. If you use the Finder search dialog, of course it's possible to select the 'Filename contains "terrible"' option manually, but I'd like to make this the default.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, there does not seem to be a way to change the default search behavior of Spotlight in Lion or Mountain Lion.

As an alternative solution, you can type `name:` followed by your search term.

For example, to find files with the term "terrible" in the filename, open Spotlight and type `name:terrible`.

Answer (score 0):

BEST alternative was given by Barney-15E at the Apple website support users forum as copied and pasted below. Thank you Barney-15E

Barney-15E  Florida
Re: Mountain Lion Spotlight searches only for filename, not for content (?)
Dec 18, 2012 4:13 AM (in response to *daniel*)

You can default to a filename search in the Finder by holding down <kbd>control</kbd> when selecting Find (<kbd>cmd</kbd> - <kbd>ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>F</kbd>)